# Alpine nested x-data

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I am trying to learn Alpine and I am testing out nested x-data. I came across a GitHub issue with nested x-data. They provided a solution which I wanted to try out myself. However, when I try to replicate the code, it didn't print anything. There are no errors in the console too. Can anyone guide me as to what I did wrong?

```
<div x-data="{foo: 'bar'}">
        <div x-data="{ }">
            <span x-text="foo"></span>
        </div>
</div>
```

I also tried using the `$el` property but it produced the same result.

Comment: Should make a note this is alpinejs v2. Merely upgrading to alpinejs v3 will result in the expected nesting behavior.

Answer (score 6):

As @LaundroMat mentioned, helper functions are built for these purpose.

```
<div x-data="{foo: 'bar'}">
    <div x-data="{localFoo: 'local bar'}">
        <span x-text="$parent.foo"></span>
        <p x-text="localFoo"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[codepen for reference](https://codepen.io/chisim/pen/qBrpwJp)

Answer (score 5):

In version 3 of `alpinejs` this issue has been solved. Nothing needs to be done.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: We're stuck with legacy AlpineJS 2

Answer (score 3):

Nesting in Alpine.js doesn't work as it does in Vue/React. When you nest a component, it doesn't have access to the parent's data, only its own.

You need to add the `foo` property to the nested `x-data` like so

```html
<div x-data="{ }">
        <div x-data="{ foo: 'bar' }">
            <span x-text="foo"></span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to append or remove new value to parent x-data in child element? Like list.append() works.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [$component/$parent helper](https://github.com/alpine-collective/alpine-magic-helpers#component) from the Alpine Magic Helpers collection.