# How to make x-data and x-show work inside nested div using alpine js

Tags: javascript, nested, alpine.js

I have very little JavaScript experience and no vue or react experience, so understanding these answers is proving to be futile. >.<

I found these 2 solutions

- [Alpine nested x-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751994/alpine-nested-x-data)
- https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/issues/49

This is the issue I am encountering.

- I got the x-data and x-show to work for the collapse sidebar button.
- When I added another x-data element in a child div that houses the content, it seems to break everything and nothing works.
- Both the sidebar div, and content div are inside the parent div that controls the collapse button.

This is how the layout looks like
[image]

This is the code of how it is somewhat layed out

```
// Div that houses main content and sidebar
<div x-data="{sidebarActive: true}"> 

    // Sidebar button
    <div @click="sidebarActive =!sidebarActive"> collapse icon </div>
    
    // kanban content
    <div x-data ="{kanbanToggle: 2}">
 
        // toggle buttons
        <div>
            <div @click="kanbanToggle: 1"> button 1 </div>
            <div @click="kanbanToggle: 2"> button 2 </div>
            <div @click="kanbanToggle: 3"> button 3 </div>
        </div>
        
        // kanban board content
        <div>
            <div x-show ="kanbanToggle ===1"> timeline view </div>
            <div x-show ="kanbanToggle ===2"> card view </div>
            <div x-show ="kanbanToggle ===3"> list view </div>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div x-show="{sidebarActive:true}"> sidebar content </div>

</div>
```

Any help much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial issue I can see with your code is that `kanbanToggle: 1` is not valid JavaScript, the correct synax is `kanbanToggle = 1`.

So replace:

```html
<div @click="kanbanToggle: 1"> button 1 </div>
<div @click="kanbanToggle: 2"> button 2 </div>
<div @click="kanbanToggle: 3"> button 3 </div>
```

with

```html
<div @click="kanbanToggle = 1"> button 1 </div>
<div @click="kanbanToggle = 2"> button 2 </div>
<div @click="kanbanToggle = 3"> button 3 </div>
```

Comment: It works now >.< I am blind haha. Idk how I missed the : vs = lol . Thank you again for the help!